# Como adicionar uma classe em JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript

Quero transformar essa linha que é jQuery em Javascript puro:

```
$('#menu #<? echo $idMenuAtivo; ?>').addClass('active');
```

Como poderia transformar-lo?

Answer (score 15):

Com navegadores **"modernos"** basta:

```
document.querySelector('#menu #<? echo $idMenuAtivo; ?>').classList.add("active");
```

Ou se quiser "alternar":

```
document.querySelector('#menu #<? echo $idMenuAtivo; ?>').classList.toggle("active");
```

Documentação:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Suporte para o `classList`:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- IE 10+
- Safari 5.1+

Comment: Bem que esse `#menu` podia sair do código, visto que a segunda parte é um `id` e será único. Só um `getElementById("<?= $idMenuAtivo ?>")` seria suficiente e, talvez, mais rápido?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu ia fazer isso, mas não sei qual o código HTML especifico, então poderia causar efeitos colaterais, é muito comum as pessoas erroneamente repetirem IDs.

Comment: De fato. Eu acreditava que esse efeito colateral aconteceria de qualquer forma, mas parece que o navegador consegue diferenciar elementos de mesmo `id` mesmo que sejam duplicados (https://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/4n7jbxzv/). Essa foi nova para mim.

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia criar sua propria função de addClass, tipo assim:

```
function addClass(element, classname){
    var currentClassList = (element.className || '').split(/\s+/);
    currentClassList
     .push(currentClassList.indexOf(classname) > -1 ? '' : classname);
    element.className = currentClassList.join(' ').trim();
}
```

Comment: Não fica mais simples utilizar o `element.classList` direto?

Comment: Claro em teoria deve funcionar em todos os Browsers menos no IE7 sua solução

Answer (score 2):

Segue exemplo de como inserir classe em javascript e remover:

```js
function addClass(id, classe) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
  var classes = elemento.className.split(' ');
  var getIndex = classes.indexOf(classe);

  if (getIndex === -1) {
    classes.push(classe);
    elemento.className = classes.join(' ');
  }
}

function delClass(id, classe) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById(id);
  var classes = elemento.className.split(' ');
  var getIndex = classes.indexOf(classe);

  if (getIndex > -1) {
    classes.splice(getIndex, 1);
  }
  elemento.className = classes.join(' ');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<button onClick="addClass('teste', 'active')">Adicionar classe</button>
<button onClick="delClass('teste', 'active')">Remover classe</button>

<div id="menu">
  <div id="teste">
    Olá!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E se existir a palavra `active` em outras classes? Essa função de remoção é bem falha.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, alterei o código para evitar este erro, realmente iria dar problema nas outras classes com o mesmo nome. Valeu aí pelo comentário, passou mega despercebido kkk

Comment: Legal que você corrigiu, assim não tem risco pros desavisados. Retirei meu negativo. Mas ainda tem uma falha: o seu `addClass` permite que a mesma classe seja incluída várias vezes na string. E o `removeClass` novo só vai remover a primeira ocorrência.

Comment: @bfavaretto, corrigido este item também! ;) acho que agora foi rsrs